# Python - Count occurrences of an item as one loops through an unsorted array

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, counter

I am having difficulty making a loop that counts the occurrences of a word in an array and when looping through said array makes another one with the current occurrence count of the word. I am able to get the total occurrences of the individual words using collections counter() but I dont necessarily need to know the total I need it incremental.

I have attempted using the dictionary made by counter() and looping back through the array but that generates an array which does half the job but the order of the original output is gone.

LOOP

```
for key, value in cnt.most_common():
    x = value
    y = 0
    for index, word in enumerate(reversed(outputList)):
        if key == word:
            if x > 0:
                outputFontSizeList.append(word + str(x-y))
                if y <= x:
                    y += 1
                else:
                    y = 0
```

OUTPUT

```
[5,4,3,2,1,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,1,1]
```

The wanted result is something detailed below, if I had list like

```
['cat','dog','neck','book','neck','bottle','apple','orange','cat','dog','cat','apple','neck','cat','dog']
```

I would after looping have an array that has counters like so corresponding the the current number of occurrences of said word matching the other array

```
[1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,2,3,4,3]
```

Comment: You do not use `index`, why do you call `enumerate`?

Comment: @DyZ Basically initially I was attempting to utilize the index and apply it but looks like my whole approach was incorrect.

Comment: There's no need to add "Solved" to your headline. When you have picked the best answer the system will marke the question as answered and shows it as green (on most platforms). I removed the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just counting as you go through rather than using `collections.Counter`. Using `collections.defaultdict(int)` might be helpful though:

```
import collections
arr = ['cat','dog','neck','book','neck','bottle','apple','orange','cat','dog','cat','apple','neck','cat','dog']
c = collections.defaultdict(int)
output = []
for word in arr:
    c[word] += 1
    output.append(c[word])
print(output)
```

Comment: thank you so much I was really racking my brain about how to get it going but its actually a much simpler solution that I thought ....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
l = ['cat','dog','neck','book','neck','bottle','apple','orange','cat','dog','cat','apple','neck','cat','dog']
s = pd.Series(l)
s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_occurences( input ):
    output = []
    occurences_dict = {}

    for word in input:
        if word in occurences_dict:
            occurences_dict[ word ] += 1
        else:
            occurences_dict[ word ] = 1
        output.append( occurences_dict[ word ] )
    return output
```

Running with:

```
input = [
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "neck",
    "book",
    "neck",
    "bottle",
    "apple",
    "orange",
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "cat",
    "apple",
    "neck",
    "cat",
    "dog"
]

print( get_occurences( input ) )
```

Gives
`[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3]`

Basically, use a dictionary to keep a running count of each word you encounter and append it to your output array. If you need the total count of each word, return the dictionary used as well.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer

```
class my_cnt:

def __init__(self):
    self.data = dict()

def count(self, val):
    if not val in self.data.keys():
        self.data.update({val : 1})
    else: 
        self.data[val] = self.data[val] + 1

    return self.data[val]

lst = ['cat','dog','neck','book','neck','bottle','apple','orange','cat','dog','cat','apple','neck','cat','dog']
cnt = my_cnt()

output = [cnt.count(e) for e in lst]
print(output)
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP is trying to accomplish actually. His desired output is the count of occurrences up to that point